# Python Pandas replicate rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If the dataframe looks like:

```
Store,Dept,Date,Weekly_Sales,IsHoliday
1,1,2010-02-05,24924.5,FALSE
1,1,2010-02-12,46039.49,TRUE
1,1,2010-02-19,41595.55,FALSE
1,1,2010-02-26,19403.54,FALSE
1,1,2010-03-05,21827.9,FALSE
1,1,2010-03-12,21043.39,FALSE
1,1,2010-03-19,22136.64,FALSE
1,1,2010-03-26,26229.21,FALSE
1,1,2010-04-02,57258.43,FALSE
```

And I wanna duplicate rows with `IsHoliday` equal to TRUE, I can do:

```
is_hol = df['IsHoliday'] == True
df_try = df[is_hol]
df=df.append(df_try*10)
```

But is there a better way to do this as I need to duplicate holiday rows  5 times, and I have to append 5 times if using the above way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788508/replicating-rows-in-pandas/50788670#50788670

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can put `df_try` inside a list and then do what you have in mind:

```
>>> df.append([df_try]*5,ignore_index=True)

    Store  Dept       Date  Weekly_Sales IsHoliday
0       1     1 2010-02-05      24924.50     False
1       1     1 2010-02-12      46039.49      True
2       1     1 2010-02-19      41595.55     False
3       1     1 2010-02-26      19403.54     False
4       1     1 2010-03-05      21827.90     False
5       1     1 2010-03-12      21043.39     False
6       1     1 2010-03-19      22136.64     False
7       1     1 2010-03-26      26229.21     False
8       1     1 2010-04-02      57258.43     False
9       1     1 2010-02-12      46039.49      True
10      1     1 2010-02-12      46039.49      True
11      1     1 2010-02-12      46039.49      True
12      1     1 2010-02-12      46039.49      True
13      1     1 2010-02-12      46039.49      True
```

Answer (score 52):

Other way is **using concat() function**:

```
import pandas as pd

In [603]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list("abc"),'col2':range(3)},index = range(3))

In [604]: df
Out[604]: 
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     2

In [605]: pd.concat([df]*3, ignore_index=True) # Ignores the index
Out[605]: 
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     2
3    a     0
4    b     1
5    c     2
6    a     0
7    b     1
8    c     2

In [606]: pd.concat([df]*3)
Out[606]: 
  col1  col2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     2
0    a     0
1    b     1
2    c     2
```

Comment: This should be preferred over accepted answer, not that `append()` got deprecated.

Comment: How does this answer the question of replicating specific rows that match some expression?

Answer (score 29):

This is an old question, but since it still comes up at the top of my results in Google, here's another way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list("abc"),'col2':range(3)},index = range(3))
```

Say you want to replicate the rows where col1="b".

```
reps = [3 if val=="b" else 1 for val in df.col1]
df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, reps)]
```

You could replace the `3 if val=="b" else 1` in the list interpretation with another function that could return 3 if val=="b" or 4 if val=="c" and so on, so it's pretty flexible.

Comment: This will also replicate the index values as well, correct?

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it wrong but this is very slow for me.

Comment: This more elegant way is also pretty fast for me compared with using .append(..). My use case is just to replicate a dataframe with a single row 1000x of times.

Comment: Not scalable: try doing `for val in df.col1` on 100 million line dataframe.. :(

Answer (score 8):

Appending and concatenating is usually slow in Pandas so I recommend just making a new list of the rows and turning that into a dataframe (unless appending a single row or concatenating a few dataframes).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
[1,1,'2010-02-05',24924.5,False],
[1,1,'2010-02-12',46039.49,True],
[1,1,'2010-02-19',41595.55,False],
[1,1,'2010-02-26',19403.54,False],
[1,1,'2010-03-05',21827.9,False],
[1,1,'2010-03-12',21043.39,False],
[1,1,'2010-03-19',22136.64,False],
[1,1,'2010-03-26',26229.21,False],
[1,1,'2010-04-02',57258.43,False]
], columns=['Store','Dept','Date','Weekly_Sales','IsHoliday'])

temp_df = []
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    if row.IsHoliday:
        temp_df.extend([list(row)]*5)
    else:
        temp_df.append(list(row))

df = pd.DataFrame(temp_df, columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: For the record, it is probably faster to do an outer join but the code gets quite convoluted for a small gain.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in one line:

```
df.append([df[df['IsHoliday'] == True]] * 5, ignore_index=True)
```

or

```
df.append([df[df['IsHoliday']]] * 5, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative to `append()` is to first replace the values of a column by a list of entries and then `explode()` (either using `ignore_index=True` or not, depending on what you want):

```
df['IsHoliday'] = df['IsHoliday'].apply(lambda x: 5*[x] if (x == True) else x)

df.explode('IsHoliday', ignore_index=True)
```

The nice thing about this one is that you can already use the list in the `apply()` call to build copies of rows with modified values in a column, in case you wanted to do that later anyways...

Comment: This is the best of all answers!!