# Method chaining df. duplicate every row 3 times

Tags: pandas, method-chaining

I have the following data frame:

**Data Frame:**

```
id animal
1  dog
2  cat
3  rabbit
4  horse
5  fox
```

I want to replicate each id 3 times. How can I do this in pandas using method chaining?

**Expected output:**

```
id animal
1  dog
1  dog
1  dog
2  cat
2  cat
2  cat
3  rabbit
3  rabbit
3  rabbit
4  horse
4  horse
4  horse
5  fox
5  fox
5  fox
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replicate rows of a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788508/how-can-i-replicate-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to chain your duplication:

```
df.loc[lambda d: d.index.repeat(3)]
```

Or:

```
df.pipe(lambda d: d.loc[d.index.repeat(3)])
```

Output:

```
   id  animal
0   1     dog
0   1     dog
0   1     dog
1   2     cat
1   2     cat
1   2     cat
2   3  rabbit
2   3  rabbit
2   3  rabbit
3   4   horse
3   4   horse
3   4   horse
4   5     fox
4   5     fox
4   5     fox
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`pandas.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(3)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

or

```
df.set_index('id').reindex(df['id'].repeat(3)).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    id  animal
0    1     dog
1    1     dog
2    1     dog
3    2     cat
4    2     cat
5    2     cat
6    3  rabbit
7    3  rabbit
8    3  rabbit
9    4   horse
10   4   horse
11   4   horse
12   5     fox
13   5     fox
14   5     fox
```