# How to repeat the Same data multiple times in a text file

Tags: python

I have some data in text file, I want to repeat it multiple times. For example 1000 records

```
CustomerID, FirstName,LastName,phone

1,Orlando,Gee,245-555-0173   
2,Keith,Harris ,170-555-0127  
3,Donna,Carreras ,279-555-0130   
4,Janet,Gates,710-555-0173   
5,Lucy,Harrington,828-555-0186   
6,Rosmarie,Carroll,244-555-0112
```

I want output like

```
CustomerID, FirstName,LastName,phone

1,Orlando,Gee,245-555-0173   
2,Keith,Harris ,170-555-0127  
3,Donna,Carreras ,279-555-0130   
4,Janet,Gates,710-555-0173   
5,Lucy,Harrington,828-555-0186   
6,Rosmarie,Carroll,244-555-0112
7,Orlando,Gee,245-555-0173   
8,Keith,Harris ,170-555-0127  
9,Donna,Carreras ,279-555-0130   
10,Janet,Gates,710-555-0173   
11,Lucy,Harrington,828-555-0186   
12,Rosmarie,Carroll,244-555-0112
--------------------
----------------------
994,Orlando,Gee,245-555-0173   
995,Keith,Harris ,170-555-0127  
996,Donna,Carreras ,279-555-0130   
997,Janet,Gates,710-555-0173   
998,Lucy,Harrington,828-555-0186   
999,Rosmarie,Carroll,244-555-0112
```

How can i proceed on this

Comment: I suggest using some sort of python script.

Comment: yes I'm looking for answer in python only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas replicate rows in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029659/python-pandas-replicate-rows-in-dataframe)

Comment: its a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029659/python-pandas-replicate-rows-in-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read your text file into pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pd_df = pd.read_csv('untitled.txt')
pd_df 



CustomerID  FirstName   LastName    phone
1           Orlando     Gee         245-555-0173
2           Keith       Harris      170-555-0127
3           Donna       Carreras    279-555-0130
4           Janet       Gates       710-555-0173
5           Lucy        Harrington  828-555-0186
6           Rosmarie    Carroll     244-555-0112
```

Then manipulate and write it back to text:

```
pd_df = pd_df.append([pd_df]*int(1000/6),ignore_index=True)
pd_df.loc[:,'CustomerID'] = range(1, pd_df.shape[0]+1)
pd_df = pd_df[pd_df.CustomerID<1000]
pd_df.to_csv('output.txt', index=False)
```