# create n copies of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, append, concatenation

What is the fastest way to expand (copy n times) the rows of a dataframe based on a value of a column. So, if the value of the column in that row is 10, that row has to be copied 10 times.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,45], "B":[2,3]})
```

*operation*

The result should look like this:

```
A   B
1   2
1   2
45  3
45  3
45  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make do with `repeat` and `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['B'])]
```

Output:

```
    A  B
0   1  2
0   1  2
1  45  3
1  45  3
1  45  3
```

Comment: this gives an error, "TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: it worked with changing the code to df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['B']).astype('int')]

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, df['B'])]
```

Repeats the row in specific index for the number of times specified in column B.

Also you can try and look here: [Python Pandas replicate rows in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029659/python-pandas-replicate-rows-in-dataframe)
Not exactly the same need but a lot of solutions to learn from for replicating rows.

Comment: this gives an error, "TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Answer (score 1):

We could also use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html)

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['B']))
    A  B
0   1  2
0   1  2
1  45  3
1  45  3
1  45  3
```

if you need:

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['B']).astype(int))
```

Comment: this gives an error, "TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: try: `df.index.repeat(df['B']).astype(int)`