# Create Duplicate Row With Date Equals +1 Day of Original Date

Tags: python, pandas

I have data table that looks like this:

```
Date            Name
12/1/2020       Golikeri, Dave
12/2/2020       Mewman, Tim 
12/6/2020       Nang, Bob
12/9/2020       Book, Tom
```

For each record in in the data table, I want to create duplicate but the duplicate `DATE` would equal the day after the original date. So for example, the new table would look like this:

```
Date            Name
12/1/2020       Golikeri, Dave
12/2/2020       Golikeri, Dave
12/2/2020       Mewman, Tim 
12/3/2020       Mewman, Tim 
12/6/2020       Nang, Bob
12/7/2020       Nang, Bob
12/9/2020       Book, Tom
12/10/2020      Book, Tom
```

Not quite sure where to even begin with this question but hoping someone would generously lead me on the right path - thanks!

Comment: what code have you tried so far please? You have been on SO so you should already know that we will want to see your work effort. Thanks for sharing your work effort.

Comment: @JoeFerndz I honestly hadn't any code yet, I came across this post but was only digging myself into a deeper hole of confusion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029659/python-pandas-replicate-rows-in-dataframe

Comment: Yes, replicate the row, then for the second value, you can always timedelta. Alternate, is what Quang did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

out = (pd.concat([df, df.assign(Date=df['Date']+pd.Timedelta('1D')) ] )
         .sort_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
        Date            Name
0 2020-12-01  Golikeri, Dave
0 2020-12-02  Golikeri, Dave
1 2020-12-02     Mewman, Tim
1 2020-12-03     Mewman, Tim
2 2020-12-06       Nang, Bob
2 2020-12-07       Nang, Bob
3 2020-12-09       Book, Tom
3 2020-12-10       Book, Tom
```

Comment: pd.Timedelta('1D') is the way to go. We could also do a repeat of the df, then replace the duplicated row with Timedelta. ?

Comment: @JoeFerndz certainly, that could work too.

Comment: thanks - works great! for my own learning purposes, can you explain how the concat and assign commands function in this code?

Comment: assign is sort-hand for `df1 = df.copy(); df1['Date'] = df['Date'] + ...` and `concat` is just stacking the frames on top of each other.