# Duplicate rows and rename DataFrame indexes using a list of suffixes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I have a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html) DataFrame object `df` as follow:

```py
              P0  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6   P7   P8   P9  P10  P11  P12  P13
object                                                                  
A            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
E            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
F            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
G            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
```

for which I'd like to duplicate each using a list of suffixes:

```py
              P0  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6   P7   P8   P9  P10  P11  P12  P13
object                                                                  
A_XS         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
A_S          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
A_M          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
A_L          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
A_XL         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
A            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B_XS         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B_S          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B_M          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B_L          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B_XL         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C_XS         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C_S          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C_M          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C_L          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C_XL         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D_XS         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D_S          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D_M          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D_L          NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D_XL         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
E            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
F            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
G            NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
```

The list of suffixes is: `list_of_suffixes = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '']` and the list of indexes that must be changed is: `list_init = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`.
Notice `E`, `F` and `G` are left untouched from the original DataFrame.

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50490890/6630397 I was able to duplicate the desired rows of my initial DataFrame `df` to the right number according to the length of the list `list_of_suffixes`:

```py
list_init = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list_of_suffixes = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '']
reps = [len(list_of_suffixes) if k in list_init else 1 for k in df.index]
df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, reps)]
```

But now all my DataFrame indices are an array of 10 of each `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` (except for `E`, `F` and `G` where there are only 1 row) where I'd like them to follow the pattern of suffixes from `list_of_suffixes` as shown here above.

How could I *elegantly* achieve that with good performances?

(note: if it's much better to work from a column containing the indexes it's also fine, because my objects `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` and `G` in the index column previously come from a standalone column named `objects`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first compute a list containing the new indexes for each row, then explode that list:

```
newvals = [['{}{}'.format(i,j) for j in ('_' + k if k != '' else k
                                         for k in list_of_suffixes)]
           if i in list_init else [i] for i in df.index]
df.reset_index().assign(object=newvals).explode('object').set_index('object')
```

gives as expected:

```
        P0  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5   P6   P7   P8   P9  P10  P11  P12  P13
object                                                                
A_XS   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
A_S    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
A_M    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
A_L    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
A_XL   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
A      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B_XS   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B_S    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B_M    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B_L    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B_XL   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
B      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C_XS   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C_S    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C_M    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C_L    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C_XL   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
C      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D_XS   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D_S    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D_M    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D_L    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D_XL   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
D      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
E      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
F      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
G      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
```