# Replicate X times specific rows of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and want to replicate specific rows based on value in a column and looking for a simple way to do it.
For example in the dummy data how can i replicate row where Age is 24 - 2 more times and where Age is 22 - 2 more times.

```
import pandas as pd

data= [['Karan',23],['Rohit',22],['Macron',22], ['Sahil',21],['Aryan',24]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','Age'])
```

So my final dataframe should look like [row order not important]

```
Name Age
Karan 23
Rohit 22
Rohit 22
Macron 22
Macron 22
Sahil 21
Aryan 24
Aryan 24
```

Tried [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029659/python-pandas-replicate-rows-in-dataframe] but no working for data with string.

Comment: does rows order matter?

Comment: not importnt, any order is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html):

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Age'].isin([22,24]).add(1))]
```

How it works:

- determine whether Age is in [22,24]
- add 1 (the `False` values become `1`, the `True` become `2`)
- repeat the index and reindex

or, for more flexibility, with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), you can pick any value you want:

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[df.index.repeat(np.where(df['Age'].isin([22,24]), 2, 1))]
```

output:

```
     Name  Age
0   Karan   23
1   Rohit   22
1   Rohit   22
2  Macron   22
2  Macron   22
3   Sahil   21
4   Aryan   24
4   Aryan   24
```

###### resetting the index:

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Age'].isin([22,24]).add(1))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
     Name  Age
0   Karan   23
1   Rohit   22
2   Rohit   22
3  Macron   22
4  Macron   22
5   Sahil   21
6   Aryan   24
7   Aryan   24
```

Comment: it is working but it is also duplicating the index. and when i reset the index with drop=True and inplace=True. the duplicate row is deleted.

Comment: If you add `.reset_index(drop=True)`, this should give you a clean index keeping the new duplicates

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution (rows order is not preserved):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mask = df['Age'].isin([22, 24])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((
    np.repeat(df[mask].values, 2, axis=0),
    df[~mask].values
)), columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
     Name Age
0   Rohit  22
1   Rohit  22
2  Macron  22
3  Macron  22
4   Aryan  24
5   Aryan  24
6   Karan  23
7   Sahil  21
```