# Merging data frames together

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have two tables, on is called *df_information*. This table just have information about each user. Here is how it looks:

| id_user | job_function | job_area | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1123 | Compensation / Benefit Policy | Human Resources | personnel |
| 1124 | HR Systems Administration | Human Resources | personnel |
| 1124 | Cyber Security / Information Security | IT / Computers / Electronic | personnel |
| 1125 | Equipment | Manufacturing / Production / Operations | manager |
| 1602 | Product Development | IT / Computers / Electronics | director |

And I have second table that is called *df_all_possible_job_function_job_area*. This table has job_function and job_area combinations that are not included in *df_information* for each title.

| job_function | job_area | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ASIC / Layout Design | TwoIT / Computers / Electronics | director |
| Accounting | Finance / Accounting | personnel |
| Accounts Payable | Finance / Accounting | personnel |
| Account Management | Customer Support / Client Services | personnel |

I want to merge *df_information* with *df_all_possible_job_function_job_area*, but the thing is each job_function, job_area combination for each title in df_information should be merged for every id_user, for example if merging two small dataframe above, something like this should be gotten in result:

| id_user | job_function | job_area | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1123 | Compensation / Benefit Policy | Human Resources | personnel |
| 1123 | Accounting | Finance / Accounting | personnel |
| 1123 | Accounting | Finance / Accounting | personnel |
| 1123 | Accounts Payable | Finance / Accounting | personnel |
| 1123 | Account Management | Customer Support / Client Services | personnel |
| 1124 | HR Systems Administration | Human Resources | personnel |
| 1124 | Cyber Security / Information Security | IT / Computers / Electronic | personnel |
| 1124 | Accounting | Finance / Accounting | personnel |
| 1124 | Accounting | Finance / Accounting | personnel |
| 1124 | Accounts Payable | Finance / Accounting | personnel |
| 1124 | Account Management | Customer Support / Client Services | personnel |
| 1125 | Equipment | Manufacturing / Production / Operations | manager |
| 1602 | Product Development | IT / Computers / Electronics | director |
| 1602 | ASIC / Layout Design | TwoIT / Computers / Electronics | director |

Answer (score 1):

You would have to specify a user code in the dataframe if you wanted to do this simply through a merge. Also you want duplicates of Accounting through the merge?

If you had a `user_code` column within `df_all_possible_job_function_job_area` you could do:

```
df = pd.concat([df_information,df_all_possible_job_function_job_area],axis=0)
df = df.sort_values(by=['id_user'],axis=0)
```

This would get you:

```
   id_user                           job_function                                 job_area      title
0     1123          Compensation / Benefit Policy                          Human Resources  personnel
1     1123                             Accounting                     Finance / Accounting  personnel
2     1123                       Accounts Payable                     Finance / Accounting  personnel
1     1124              HR Systems Administration                          Human Resources  personnel
2     1124  Cyber Security / Information Security              IT / Computers / Electronic  personnel
3     1124                     Account Management       Customer Support / Client Services  personnel
3     1125                              Equipment  Manufacturing / Production / Operations    manager
4     1602                    Product Development             IT / Computers / Electronics   director
0     1602                   ASIC / Layout Design          TwoIT / Computers / Electronics   director
```

Otherwise without the `id_user` column, you are looking at:

```
0   1123.0          Compensation / Benefit Policy                          Human Resources  personnel
1   1124.0              HR Systems Administration                          Human Resources  personnel
2   1124.0  Cyber Security / Information Security              IT / Computers / Electronic  personnel
3   1125.0                              Equipment  Manufacturing / Production / Operations    manager
4   1602.0                    Product Development             IT / Computers / Electronics   director
0      NaN                   ASIC / Layout Design          TwoIT / Computers / Electronics   director
1      NaN                             Accounting                     Finance / Accounting  personnel
2      NaN                       Accounts Payable                     Finance / Accounting  personnel
3      NaN                     Account Management       Customer Support / Client Services  personnel
```

Because there is not common values to connect this data with.

For the duplication, you would need
`1124,"Accounting","Finance / Accounting","personnel"`
as a row in the first dataframe. There are then other documentation on duplicating certain rows such as: [Python Pandas replicate rows in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029659/python-pandas-replicate-rows-in-dataframe) which can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

not the most elegant way, but Outer join will solve some part of the question. and because your second table does not have id_user, the value will show as NaN. for that table.

```
merged = df_information.merge(df_all_possible_job_function_job_area, on=['job_function','job_area','title'], how="outer")
```

merged table will look like this:
[image]